# Various graphical, audio, and input glitches since dual booting Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics

I am currently dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 10, having previously been a Windows user. Since installing Ubuntu I have had several issues which never appeared before and which only  affect the Ubuntu partition.

The issues are:

1. Programs taking a long (and highly variable) time for my input to be registered (e.g. text not appearing for several seconds, mouse not moving)
2. Audio occasionally cutting out for brief periods (~1s) and sometimes no audio at all until restarting
3. Computer not always waking up from sleep mode
4. Things taking longer than usual for screen to update (load times seem unaffected)
5. Failing to register keyboard inputs or registering too many (e.g., "aaaa" instead of "a")
6. When booting the screen will flash black with a mesh of purple pictures at the bottom right area of the screen
7. Seeing my desktop folders superimposed on the window I'm using (this has only happened once or twice)
8. Video freezing for brief periods (~1s) and occasionally flashing black

**Strangely these issues only sometimes occur**. Typically if they occur after one boot, they will appear in the next one also but there are also periods of 3 or more boots where there are no issues. It doesn't seem to be more likely to occur if my last boot was in Windows. Overall, these issues occur on about 1/4 of boots - though that is just an rough estimate.

My CPU and memory usage is also low so this is not the issue.

I have tried the following to resolve my issue but not have worked:

1. Turning off secure boot on Windows
2. Updating Ubuntu with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`
3. Checking my drivers (I am using proprietary Nvidia drivers)
4. Running an anti-virus scan with ClamAV

I attempted to switch to open source drivers to see if there would be any effect. However, it appeared to become stuck installing.

Here is my system information:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- Memory: 7.7 GiB
- Processor: Intel Core i7-8565 (1.80GHz)
- Graphics Card: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile
- Computer Model: HP Pavilion 15-cs1506sa